# Property 'validateFile' does not exist on type 'FileReader'

Tags: javascript

I have a csv file which I need to validate.
here is the function:

```
 let reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function (e) {
      let resultFile = e.target.result
      let value = this.validateFile((<String>resultFile).split('\n'))
      if (value != "valid") {
        errors += value;
        return errors;
      }
  }
```

I need to do some validation inside the function validateFile.

```
validateFile(data) {
     if ((fileLength <= batchProp.MAX_SUBREQUESTS_WITH_OFFERS && this.includeOffers) || (fileLength <= batchProp.MAX_SUBREQUESTS_WITHOUT_OFFERS && !this.includeOffers)) {
  if (!this.checkUploadedFile(data, fileLength)) {
    this.lastRowWasValid = true;
    }
  }
}
```

But I keep getting this error:

> Property 'validateFile' does not exist on type 'FileReader'.

Please suggest how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a arrow function to access the global scope which has the validateFile function

```
let reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function (e) => {
      let resultFile = e.target.result
      let value = this.validateFile((<String>resultFile).split('\n'))
      if (value != "valid") {
        errors += value;
        return errors;
      }
  }
```

Comment: It worked! But can you explain why this solution worked?

Comment: There are many articles that explain this, you can read this https://levelup.gitconnected.com/arrow-function-vs-regular-function-in-javascript-b6337fb87032